# remove an extra empty list while splitting lines from file-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open a file which has two sentences and split the the two sentences into a list of words. However, when I do that I also get an extra empty list, how can this be prevented?

```
x1=[]
fopen=open("testxxx",'r')
for line in fopen:
   x=line.split()
   x1.append(x)
print x1
```

I get:

```
[['i', 'have', 'a', 'dog'], ['i', 'have', 'a', 'cat'], []]
```

Comment: It means that you have an empty line at the bottom. Delete it.

Comment: It means that you have an empty line at the bottom *which some elementary debugging would have found*

Answer (score 5):

Use `splitlines()` to read all lines of the file into a list:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()
```

Split the lines with this list comprehension:

```
mylist = [line.split() for line in mylist]
```

Use `filter()` to remove any empty list items:

```
mylist = filter(None, mylist)
```

---

You could also do all of that while you are reading the file:

```
mylist = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            mylist.append(line.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x1=[]
fopen=open("testxxx",'r')
for line in fopen:
   x=line.split()
   if x:
       x1.append(x)
print x1
```

Answer (score 0):

remove empty list :

```
x1= [x for x in x1 if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readlines`:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    mylist = [line for line in f.readlines() if line.strip() != '']
```

Or:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip() != '':
            lines.append(line)
```

Or:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = filter(lambda x: x.strip() != '', f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the read line is empty or not as you try splitting its words.

```
word_list = []
lines = []

with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    # stripping the whitespaces as the blank line may contain whitespaces
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

# split to words those lines that are not empty strings
word_list = [line.split() for line in lines if line]
```

#### OR, with a one-liner

```
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    word_list = [line.split() for line in file.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

Note that empty string `''` is falsy in python. So, naturally if `line` is a empty string, `if line` evaluates to False, and likewise for `line.strip()`. Take a look here for [truth-value-testing](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in python.